# Python LevelDB (plyvel) - How to restore links of onetab from its leveldb

Tags: python, leveldb

I'm trying to restore my links of leveldb via plyvel, But I can't convert link keys to real url and Also I see some links in value json but not sure they are correct.

Anybody have any idea how to do this?

Here is my code

```
import plyvel
db = plyvel.DB(
        '~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage/leveldb'
        , create_if_missing=False)

for key, value in db:
    print("Key: ", key)
    #print("Key: ", key.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
    print("Value: ", value)

db.close()
```

and there is a sample result

```
Key:  b'_https://medium.com\x00\x01optimizely_data$$lo_30d0ccb22b41$$16180790160$$event_queue'
Value:  b'\x01[{"eb":{"n":"16180790160_logged_out_meters_all_meters_metrics_only","y":"pageview","c":"other"},"h":"8b5f4c5b","tb":1640813539983,"ts":[{"d":0,"i":0}]}]'
Key:  b'_https://medium.com\x00\x01optimizely_data$$lo_30d0ccb22b41$$16180790160$$layer_map'
Value:  b'\x01{}'
```